# Keeping a track of duplicate inserts in a Map (Multithreaded environment)

Tags: java, multithreading, duplicates, spring-batch, concurrenthashmap

I am looking for a way to keep a track of the number of times the same key insert is attempted into a `Map` in a multithreaded environemnt such that the `Map` can be read and updated by multiple threads at the same time. If keeping a track of duplicate key insert attempts is not achievable easily, an alternate solution would be to kill the application at the first sign of a duplicate key insert attempt.

The following user defined singleton Spring bean shows a global cache used by my application which is loaded using multiple partitioned spring batch jobs (one job for each `DataType` to be loaded). The `addResultForDataType` method can be called by multiple threads at the same time.

```
public class JobResults {

    private Map<DataType, Map<String, Object>> results;

    public JobResults() {
        results = new ConcurrentHashMap<DataType, Map<String, Object>>();
    }

    public void addResultForDataType(DataType dataType, String uniqueId, Object result) {
        Map<String, Object> dataTypeMap = results.get(dataType);
        if (dataTypeMap == null) {
            synchronized (dataType) {
                dataTypeMap = results.get(dataType);
                if (dataTypeMap == null) {
                    dataTypeMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();
                    results.put(dataType, dataTypeMap);
                }
            }
        }
        dataTypeMap.put(uniqueId, result);
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getResultForDataType(DataType dataType) {
        return results.get(dataType);
    }

}
```

**Here :**

- `DataType` can be thought of as the table name or file name from
  where the data is loaded. Each DataType indicates one table or file.
- `uniqueId` represents the primary key for each record in the table or file.
- `result` is the object representing the entire row.
- The above method is called once per record. At any given time, multiple threads can be inserting a record for the same `DataType` or a different `DataType`.

I thought of creating another map to keep a track of the duplicate inserts :

```
public class JobResults {

    private Map<DataType, Map<String, Object>> results;
    private Map<DataType, ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>> duplicates;

    public JobResults() {
        results = new ConcurrentHashMap<DataType, Map<String, Object>>();
        duplicates = new ConcurrentHashMap<DataType, ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>>();
    }

    public void addResultForDataType(DataType dataType, String uniqueId, Object result) {
        Map<String, Object> dataTypeMap = results.get(dataType);
        ConcurrentHashMap<String,Integer> duplicateCount = duplicates.get(dataType);
        if (dataTypeMap == null) {
            synchronized (dataType) {
                dataTypeMap = results.get(dataType);
                if (dataTypeMap == null) {
                    dataTypeMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();
                    duplicateCount = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>();
                    results.put(dataType, dataTypeMap);
                    duplicates.put(dataType, duplicateCount);
                }
            }
        }
        duplicateCount.putIfAbsent(uniqueId, 0);
        duplicateCount.put(uniqueId, duplicateCount.get(uniqueId)+1);//keep track of duplicate rows
        dataTypeMap.put(uniqueId, result);
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getResultForDataType(DataType dataType) {
        return results.get(dataType);
    }

}
```

I realize that the statemet `duplicateCount.put(uniqueId, duplicateCount.get(uniqueId)+1);` is not implicitly thread safe. To make it thread-safe, I will need to use synchronization which will slow down my inserts. How can I keep a track of the duplicate inserts without impacting the performance of my application. If keeping a track of duplicate inserts is not easy, I would be fine with just throwing an exception at the first sign of an attempt to overwrite an existing entry in the map.

**Note** I am aware that a `Map` does not allow duplicate keys. What I want is a way to keep a track of any such attempts and halt the application rather than overwrite entries in the `Map`.

Comment: Are you looking to avoid the duplicates on the outer or inner `Map`?

Comment: @Actorclavilis Just the outer map. (See my attempt at the solution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
    ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicInteger> duplicateCount = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, AtomicInteger>();
```

Then when you're ready to increment a count, do this:

```
final AtomicInteger oldCount = duplicateCount.putIfAbsent(uniqueId, new AtomicInteger(1));
if (oldCount != null) {
    oldCount.incrementAndGet();
}
```

So, if you do not have a count in the map yet, you will put 1, if you have, you will get the current value and atomically increment it. This should be thread safe.

Comment: using atomic one after the other doesn't make the whole being atomic

Comment: It either puts a new AtomicInteger with value 1 or increments an existing AtomicInteger. It does not use both at the same time. I guess, you can always do something like this:
final AtomicInteger oldCount = duplicateCount.putIfAbsent(uniqueId, new AtomicInteger(1));

if (oldCount != null) {
    oldCount.incrementAndGet();
}

Comment: The caveat in your code is that there is no "happens-before" relationship established between reading oldCount and performing the null check. Obviously, in the current context - it doesn't matter, but worth calling it out nevertheless.

Comment: @PeterL The statements `final AtomicInteger oldCount = duplicateCount.putIfAbsent(uniqueId, new AtomicInteger(1));` and the entire `if` statement are running one after another instead of being one atomic operation. This still does not guarentee thread safery right? Also, what is the impact of this solution on the overall performance

Comment: @Ping, yes, they run one after another. However, because it uses ConcurrentHashMap and putIfAbsent call, it is guaranteed that all threads get the same AtomicInteger instance per uniqueID. Since AtomicInteger. incrementAndGet is thread safe, you will not have any issues. The performance impact is minimal. ConcurrentHashMap is pretty efficient and AtomicInteger is very fast as it does not use any synchronized calls.

Comment: @PeterL This seems to have worked as expected. I am still evaluating the performance impact of this on the application considering this increases the memory usage of the application as a result of holding all the keys in the duplicateCount map. Thanks for your answer; however, is there any other way to do this rather than holding a seperate `Map`? Like I said, I am fine with killing the application when the first duplicate row is encountered without the need to report all duplicate rows.

Comment: @Ping, if you do not care about counting the duplicates, and can kill the app, they you can simply need to abort if there was something in the map already:

Object oldResult = dataTypeMap.putIfAbsent(uniqueId, result);
if (oldResult != null) System.exit(1);

or whatever you need to do do abort (maybe, log uniqueId, oldResult, and result just in case).

Comment: @PeterL `dataTypeMap.putIfAbsent(uniqueId, result);` would still mean that the unique id's would get inserted in another `Map`. Worst case scenario would be that there are no duplicates and you would end up with a `Map` that will have all the unique id's thus resulting in unneccesary memory consumption. Once again, your answer does help. But I was hoping there was another way to do this rather than requiring a separate `Map` that will hold all the unique ids. There are millions of records per file/table and I am dealing with 9 files/tables. That's 9 million keys in the `duplcateCount` `Map`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep track of the number of inserts, you can change the outer map type to something like `Map<String, Pair<Integer, Object>>` (or, if you don't use Apache Commons, just `Map<DataType, Map.Entry<Integer, InnerType>>`, where the `Integer` value is the number of updates:

```
DataType key = ...;
Map<Integer, Object> value = ...;
dataTypeMap.compute(key, (k, current) -> {
    if (current == null) {
        /* Initial count is 0 */
        return Pair.of(0, value);
    } else {
        /* Increment count */
        return Pair.of(current.getFirst(), value);
    }));
```

If all you care about is ensuring that there is no duplicate inserts, you can simply use `computeIfAbsent`:

```
DataType key = ...;
Map<Integer, Object> value = ...;
if (dataTypeMap.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> value)) != null) {
    /* There was already a value */
    throw new IllegalStateException(...);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer; however, note that changing the structure of the `Map` is not an option.